# Find matching rows in 2 excel lists based on 2 matching columns

Tags: excel

I know that similar questions have been asked but *I haven’t found the scenario that I am looking.* I want to highlight ,using conditional formatting, matching rows  in one list based on ***2 matching columns*** on another list.

On the provided picture the fifth row in the second list is highlighted because both the ID and days match with a record from the first list.

That means that I don’t care about the client and provider columns but also means that the third row won’t be highlighted ,for example, because it match the id column but not the days.

[image]

I have found examples with conditional formatting but only matching one column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concatenate and then match.

That is, make a hidden column (say, column D) in your first table with the formula

```
=A2 & "##" & C2
```

Then, to find, use the concatenate string as your lookup parameter and look in the concatenated column. Something like:

```
=IF(ISNA(MATCH(E2&"##"&G2, $D$2:$D$4, 0)), FALSE, TRUE)
```

If you don't want to use an extra column for this intermediate calculation, then look into using array formulas.

Answer (score 0):

Using your provided example, create a new conditional formatting rule that applies to $E$2:$G$7 and use this formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--($A$2:$A$4=$E2),--($C$2:$C$4=$G2))>0
```

If you're on Excel 2007 or higher, you can use the COUNTIFS formula instead of SUMPRODUCT:

```
=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$4,$E2,$C$2:$C$4,$G2)>0
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot Josh! I tried your solution with ***partial success***. First I did concatenate on rows in column “E” and used the following formula on the conditional formatting expression.

```
=IF(ISNA(MATCH(G2&I2, $E$2:$E$4, 0)), FALSE, TRUE)
```

However as shown in the picture and I only get the first column to be highlighted and I need the entire row. I am selecting the entire range when applying the conditional formatting.

[image]

**EDIT**

I found the error! the formula need some extra columns to be fixed. This is the right formula:

```
=IF(ISNA(MATCH($G2&$I2, $E$2:$E$4, 0)), FALSE, TRUE)
```

Comment: I found the error in the formula and corrected the answer to include it. Thank again for your help Josh.